# match the string to find the braces & match another string with in the braces & replace it

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

We would like to match the string DataGuardDatadgSpace & find the hostgroups string within the flower brackets & replace the string SERVER-DATABASE with SERVER-NODE1-DATABASE in the line matching the hostgroups.it shouldn't affect the servicegroups line which matches the string or remaining code.

I would like to edit this code in a file. I have tried the below option

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/DataGuardDatadgSpace/!d;' test.shee 
    | sed '/hostgroups/s/\S*$/REPLACED/g'
```

but it's not working for the file

```
define service {
    use                     generic-pasv-svc
    name                    SERVER-DATABASE-ArchdgSpace
    service_description     DataGuardArchdgSpace
    hostgroups              SERVER-DATABASE,xDB
    servicegroups           PASV,SERVER-stack,SERVER-DATABASE
    max_check_attempts      3
    check_command           check_dummy!2!"Passive check is stale"
    contact_groups          po
    check_freshness         1
    freshness_threshold     180
    register                1
}

define service {
    use                     generic-pasv-svc
    name                    SERVER-DATABASE-DatadgSpace
    service_description     DataGuardDatadgSpace
    servicegroups           PASV,SERVER-stack,SERVER-DATABASE
    max_check_attempts      3
    check_command           check_dummy!2!"Passive check is stale"
    contact_groups          po
   hostgroups              SERVER-DATABASE,xDB
    check_freshness         1
    freshness_threshold     180
    register                1
}

define service{
        use                     generic-pasv-svc
        name                    ORA_DATABASE_HangDetect_DefunctProcess
        service_description     ORA_HangDetect_DefunctProcess
        hostgroups              SERVER-DATABASE
        servicegroups           PASV
        check_command           check_dummy!3!"Passive service check is stale, check the Ora HangDetect Script is running or not"
        freshness_threshold     600
        contact_groups          po
        max_check_attempts      2
        normal_check_interval   5
        retry_check_interval    1
        register                1
}
```

Comment: Great! You have a problem statement. What have you tried so far, and how is it not working?

Comment: I have tried following but it's not replacing it in a file.My requirement is to edit the strings in a file

Comment: sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/DataGuardDatadgSpace/!d;' test.shee | sed '/hostgroups/s/\S*$/REPLACED/g'

Comment: You should [edit] your post and include that as a [mcve].

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, **that is all**. What you are trying to do is not that so you should not be considering sed. An awk script would be far simpler, clearer, more maintainable and almost certainly more robust, efficient, and portable too. You've already accepted a sed answer so I doubt if anyone will now bother to post an awk answer since you may not bother to even read it but If you post a followup question I'm sure someone will be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that hostgroup value should be `SERVER-DATABASE` and not `SERVER--DATABASE` in your sample code. If so, you can try this sed:

```
sed '/{/{:a;N;/}/!ba;/DataGuardDatadgSpace/s/\(.*hostgroups[[:space:]]*\)SERVER-DATABASE/\1SERVER-NODE1-DATABASE/;}' file
```

All lines between `{` and `}` are merged in the pattern space. If `DataGuardDatadgSpace` is found in the block, `SERVER-DATABASE` value in `hostgroups` is replaced with `SERVER- NODE1-DATABASE`.

Add the `-i` flag to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i '/{/{:a;N;/}/!ba;/DataGuardDatadgSpace/s/\(.*hostgroups[[:space:]]*\)SERVER-DATABASE/\1SERVER-NODE1-DATABASE/;}' file
```

Comment: Thank you so much.It helped to fix the issues,